# How to convert JSON to normal PDF text format or table format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, pdf

I have data which is in coming in as HTTP response. I want to get this data in a PDF.I am able to get the data in the PDF using jsPDF module but it is coming in the JSON format. I want the data in normal text format or tabular format.

My column names are "Date","Number of Products","Size","Compressed Size"

My function associated with the click button is as follows

```
downloadPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const col = ["Date","Number of Products","Size","Compressed Size"];
    const rows = [];

    for (const key in this.response){
       const temp = [key, this.response[key]];
       rows.push(temp);
    }

    doc.autoTable(col, rows);
    const filename = "test.pdf";
    doc.save(filename);
```

But with this i guess the autotable doesnt work and it even gives me an error when i import autotable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates the pdf as I tested on my local system. I used table and not autotable as I didnt find it in the document.

```
    // you can directly use your response format is array of objects

    var data =
    [{  
        Date: "29th April",
        'Number of Products': "2",
        Size: "25",
        'Compressed Size': "22",
    }];

function createHeaders(keys) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
        result.push({
        'id' : keys[i],
            'name': keys[i],
            'prompt': keys[i],
            'width': 65,
            'align': 'center',
            'padding': 0
        });
    }
    return result;
}



var headers = createHeaders(["Date", "Number of Products", "Size", "Compressed Size"]);

var doc = new jsPDF({ putOnlyUsedFonts: true, orientation: 'landscape' });
doc.table(1, 1, data, headers, { autoSize: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe   `const temp = [key, JSON.stringify(this.response[key])];`

Comment: I think the colums need also to be an array in an array